# Как перевести в формат числа, и наоборот? 0x360 = 864

Tags: hex

Есть строка в `0x360` если через гугл забить оно выводит число `864`, а что это за формат строки? И как мне перевести число в такой формат, и наоборот? Спасибо

[Нагуглил](https://www.binaryhexconverter.com/hex-to-decimal-converter), и нашел онлайн `hex` конвертер, но там не совпадает.

Если я ввожу `hexvalue => decima`

`0x360=864` выдает, верно

А если я наоборот перевожу, `decimal to hex`

`864=360` то мне `360` выдает почему-то, а не `0х360`

Answer (score 2):

`0x` в начале числа означает, что число записано в [шестнадцатеричной системе счисления](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A8%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%86%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F).

Конвертер выдает `360`, а не `0х360`, потому что и так понятно, что результат будет в шестнадцатеричной системе (Калькулятор в Windows тоже без префиксов показывает). Или программисту было просто лениво добавлять `0x` в начало строки.

`0h` - восьмеричная.

`0b` - двоичная.

Answer (score 1):

Шестнадцатеричная система счисления означает что для представления этого числа используется основание 16. Т.е. имеется 16 цифр для записи одного порядка. т.к. арабских цифр всего десять (0-9) то в дополнению к ним добавляют (A-F). 0x означает что после x ожидается число в шестнадцатиричном представлении.

Для перевода из десятичной системы в шестнадцатиричную (да и в любую другую) используют следующий алгоритм:

1. число на цело делят на основание
2. остаток от деления записываю в виде цифры (0-F), приписывая к получаемому числу слева (более высокие порядки)
3. повторяют пункт один от полученным от деления числа

т.е. в вашем случае

1. 864/16 = 54 (остаток 0) ->0
2. 54 / 16 = 3 (остаток 6) -> 60
3. 3 / 16 = 0 (остаток 3) -> 360
4. В итоге 0x360